# Programmatically configure a custom entity to use MS CRM Activity Feeds

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Haven't been able to find any info on this. I'm creating a new custom entity and I want (need) to allow activity feeds via C# code. I can find information on how to set it up interactively but not programmatically.

•What do I need to set when I define my entity?

•Do I need to add the record wall to the form or will that automatically be done when I enable activity feeds for the entity?

•If I need to take care of the record wall, is there a fieldtype/id for it not listed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc906186.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do this via the API:

> To enable an entity for activity feeds, use the msdyn_PostConfig
>   entity. Use the SetStateRequest message to activate the feeds for an
>   entity. Set the msdyn_PostConfig.msdyn_ConfigureWall attribute to true
>   to enable the wall on the entity form.

The [MSDN documentation has additional details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547386.aspx).

Comment: I had seen that but it looks like something done after the entity exists. I need to be able to define this when I define the entity in the solution file rather than add it in after the solution has been imported if possible.